# C++: Does inheriting from a class bring it into the namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Here's some contrived example code:

```
template<typename T> void Do(T arg) { (void)arg->b; }

namespace A {
    struct Foo { int a; };
}

namespace B {
    struct Foo { int b; };
    struct Bar : A::Foo {
        void Blah() { Do((Foo *)0); }
    };
}
```

Which when compiled with gcc 4.8.2 (clang gives a similar error):

```
namespacebug.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Do(T) [with T = A::Foo*]’:
namespacebug.cpp:10:34:   required from here
namespacebug.cpp:1:39: error: ‘struct A::Foo’ has no member named ‘b’
 template<typename T> void Do(T arg) { (void)arg->b; }
                                       ^
```

Note in the error it refers to `T = A::Foo` even though at the call-site I am creating a `Foo` within namespace `B`. If I remove the base class decl (`: A::Foo`) then all compiles fine.

This appears to suggest that inheriting from `A::Foo` somehow brings it into my namespace and matches it to my use of `Foo`? What C++ "feature" causes this?

(Of course, this issue can easily be fixed by namespacing my use of `Foo`, but that's not the question.)

Comment: `(void)arg->b;` - what does this mean?

Comment: @EdHeal, I think that's just there to force the error

Comment: @StoryTeller - So what is the point of doing stupid things?

Comment: @EdHeal, the point is to demonstrate that a different result is returned by the name lookup in different scenarios.

Comment: @StoryTeller - But does anybody use/write this code in the real world. I hope not. It is impossible to maintain and also not easy to understand for a maintainer. If a person writes such code then the software is going to be broken in the future if not before then

Comment: @EdHeal, while I agree that SO should direct developers to better design, this question is about a language mechanism. The example should be taken as no more than that. It will help future SO users who wish to understand the feature. Same as poor code in otherwise good books helps to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the injected-class-name rule, the name of a class is visible as though it were a member.

9/2

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen.  The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.  For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name.

So it is as though class `A::Foo` contains a member `Foo` which names the type `A::Foo`.  Since name lookup in `Bar::Blah()` considers base members of `Bar` before namespace members, the name lookup for `Foo` finds the injected-class-name, which names `A::Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

> Does inheriting from a class bring it into the namespace?

Sort of. If lookup of a name fails in the class, then lookup is continued in the base class.

> **10.2 Member name lookup**
>
> ...
>
> 5 Otherwise (i.e., `C` does not contain a declaration of `f` or the resulting declaration set is empty), *`S(f,C)`* is initially empty. If `C` has base classes, calculate the lookup set for `f` in each direct base class subobject `Bi`, and merge each such lookup set *`S(f,Bi)`* in turn into *`S(f,C)`*.

**Member name lookup** includes lookup of nested types too. Later in that same section, we find:

> 9 [ *Note:* A static member, a nested type or an enumerator defined in a base class T can unambiguously be found even if an object has more than one base class subobject of type T. Two base class subobjects share the non-static member subobjects of their common virtual base classes. *—end note* ]

Comment: That is for members. This is a type, not a member, and it matches it with the base class type.

Comment: @Aardappel Correct. However, the injected class name is a member of the base class and is inherited just like other members. Which is how you can write things like `struct A { }; struct B : A { }; int main() { B::A(); }`.

Comment: @Aardappel, the name lookup includes nested types too. See my update.

Comment: I guess you are right. Weird though, as it almost appears to violate namespace rules.